# Unable to identify WinTable on a Winforms 2000 Application using Coded UI

Tags: c#, winforms, automation, coded-ui-tests

I am developing an automation testing suite for one of our applications that was developed in WinForms 2000. I have been able to more or less work with every control except for a WinTable. When i use the Coded UI Test Builder, I am unable to identify the table. The only object being identified is the parent control which is of control type Client.

I would like any suggestions or workarounds that i could use.

I did read that one workaround to get this to work, is to create a custom control and implement the required accessibility. I have not been able to achieve this though.

I would gladly appreciate any help.

Cheers.

Comment: does anyone have an answer for this??????